# What is inconsistent number of samples?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Ian working with a machine learning problem ,This is the first time  that Iam working with a machine learning problem and it showed an error. The following is my code.

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
digits = datasets.load_digits()
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001,C=100)
X,Y = digits.data[:-1],digits.target[:-1]
X_mod  = X.reshape(-1,1)
Y_mod = Y.reshape(-1,1)

clf.fit(X_mod,Y_mod)
print("prediction is: ",clf.predict([-1]))
```

The following is the error it shows,what to do?

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of   samples: [114368, 1787]
```

Comment: Before rushing to open a question here, please take a look at the relevant [example in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#recognizing-hand-written-digits).

Answer (score 0):

You are not fitting the model properly, try the following code to fit the model:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report

#Load the digits dataset 
digits = datasets.load_digits()

#Create train-test split for accuracy validation purpose 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

#Create a Support Vector Classifier placeholder
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001,C=100)

#Fit the model on train data
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Model score on train data
clf.score(X_train, y_train)

#Make predictions on test data
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)

#Print train, test accuracy
print('Train accuracy %s' % clf.score(X_train, y_train))
print('Test accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(predictions, y_test))

#Create confusion matrix and classification report
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```

Read more about [`Confusion Matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) and [`Classification Report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)